# How to tell someone that they are wrong?

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm looking for a phrase which I could use to tell a child (age 10-14) that their answer is wrong, without offending them of course. This would be something I could on a test.... Any suggestions?

PS I'm not a teacher, but I'm designing computer software that could be used as a teaching aid.

Comment: "The answer is incorrect"? Anyway, I'd focus the statement on the answer, not the person.

Comment: Sometimes, learning that you are not right all the time is just something that a teenager has to swallow. There's no easy way of saying it. Not that I ever experienced that, of course...

Comment: If it's a test, and the individual knows it's being graded, then "Correct" or "Incorrect" is about all that's needed.  One should avoid doing a victory dance after pronouncing it incorrect, however.

Answer (score 3):

I think "almost there" is very encouraging or maybe "Try again :)"